# pyTorch DataLoader killed

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to run a pyTorch pipeline with the ResNet architecture.
Everithing is run on a CPU with the pyTorch official Docker on a Mac laptop.

Everything seems fine until I get this error:

```
Batch 23/51
Batch 24/51
Traceback (most recent call last): File "model.py", line 251, in <module>
  loss.backward()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 93, in backward
  torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 89, in backward
  allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 178, in handler
  _error_if_any_worker_fails()
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 397) is killed by signal: Killed.
```

It seems to work properly until the 24th batch of the first epoch.
The dataset is using the TensorDataset from the standard library.

Can anyone give me a hint on what is happening?
Multiple tries give different batch number (even without shuffle) and the laptop resources seem fine during the entire run.

If I try with `workers=0` for the loader I just get:

```
Batch 24/51
Batch 25/51
Batch 26/51
Batch 27/51
Batch 28/51
Killed
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just guessing, but are you using pinned memory and can try without pinning memory?

Comment: thank you mexmex. I'm running everithing over CPU. If I understood well, the choice can be made only if using GPU, am I right?

Comment: yes, that's correct! was thinking you may be using GPUs. in that case, I'm not sure. I still guess it's memory. To debug, if I was you, maybe I would try to train on random data, i.e. instead of using data_set and data_loader just create random tensors of the same shapes as your current input/ targets at every iteration. If you continue to get an error, the mistake will lie in the model (maybe hanging on to some tensors) otherwise the mistake will lie in your data loader/ dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try your suggestion!

Comment: Even with random tensors using `torch.rand` it stops with `Killed`. The thing that I can't understand is why the process gets killed without any prompt or a proper error.

Comment: Okay, seems like a useful insight though. In this case, maybe your network definition is improper? Are you using an out-of-the-box network or have you made some small modifications to network or training code? a popular error is when printing the loss. not to extract it with loss.data.item() - are you doing that?  maybe part of this is helpful: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/i-run-out-of-memory-after-a-certain-amount-of-batches-when-training-a-resnet18/1911/2

Comment: You may have found it @mexmex! I was using `loss` as a double at some point.
I'll try to run the whole epochs, but it lasted for the first one.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't worry mate! Good luck.